# C++ Class Inheritance separate methods in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I got the three classes `MachineLearning`, `MachineLearningSVM` and `MachineLearningAdaboost`.

`MachineLearning` is the base class and `MachineLearningSVM` and `MachineLearningAdaboost` derive from it.

```
class MachineLearning;      //Base class
class MachineLearningSVM : public MachineLearning;   
class MachineLearningAdaboost : public MachineLearning;

class `MachineLearning` {
   public:
      virtual void Train();
}

class MachineLearningSVM : public MachineLearning {
   public:
       void Train(std::vector<Feature> features);
}

class MachineLearningAdaboost : public MachineLearning {
   public:
       void Train(std::vector<Feature> features, std::vector<Label> labels);
}
```

My problem is that I would like to tell all deriving classes that they should keep a function Train(), but each deriving class should be able to have different parameters in their method definition. As seen above the Adaboost needs (exemplarily) additional labels for training.

Consider the following:

```
 int main(){
     MachineLearning* ml;
     switch(type){
         case SVM:
             ml = new MachineLearningSVM();
             break;
         case Adaboost:
             ml = new MachineLearningAdaboost();
             break;
     }
     ml->Train(std::vector<Feature>);
 }
```

C++ doesn't know at compile time which Train function to call, since its not clear if it will be of type SVM or Adaboost.

How could I implement this scenario? I want to avoid using templates.

Comment: What exact "scenario" do you want to implement? If you know at _code-write_ time what type you will have, then why bother having a base class? If you do not know at _code-write_ time what type you will have, how do _you_ (not the compiler, but you!) know whether you need to provide `labels`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fundamentally misunderstood the concept of polymorphism and inheritance. The derived class must have an *is-a* relationship to the base class: `MachineLearningSVM` **is a** `MachineLearning`, in particular the `virtual` functions declared in the base (but defined or overridden in the derived class) will be callable from a pointer to base.

In your example, this makes no sense:

```
MachineLearning*ptr = get_machine_learning(); // can be either derived class
ptr->Train();           // we don't know which derived class so what do you
                        // want to pass as arguments???
```

You could define a more flexible interface, but then you still have the same problem (as obvious by the exceptions):

```
struct MachineLearning
{
  void Train(std::vector<Feature> const&features)
  {
    if(need_labels()) throw std::runtime_error("need labels to train");
    train(features);
  }
  void Train(std::vector<Feature> const&features,
             std::vector<Label> const&labels)
  {
    if(!need_labels()) std::cerr<<"WARNING: ignoring labels for training\n";
    train(features,labels);
  }
  virtual~MachineLearning() {}
protected:
  virtual void train(std::vector<Feature> const&) = 0;
  virtual void train(std::vector<Feature> const&,
                     std::vector<Label> const&) = 0;
  virtual bool need_labels() const = 0;
};

struct MachineLearningSVM : MachineLearning
{
protected:
  bool need_labels() const { return false; }
  void train(std::vector<Feature> const&features) override;
  void train(std::vector<Feature> const&features,
             std::vector<Label> const&) override
  { train(features); }
};

struct MachineLearningAdaboost : public MachineLearning
{
protected:
  bool need_labels() const { return true; }
  void train(std::vector<Feature> const&) override
  { throw std::runtime_error("need labels for training"); }
  void train(std::vector<Feature> const&features,
             std::vector<Label> const&labels) override;
};
```

These errors and warnings are the hallmark of a poor code design ...

Comment: Thanks! That was a real eye-opener to me! I will use two separate classes, one for SVM and one for Adaboost now and drop the inheritance.

Comment: you're welcome! If you found this post useful, you may also considering upvoting ...

Comment: I definitly would, but I dont have enough reputation atm

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that in C++ function signature is created using its name, and the types of parametres passed into it.
The base class does *not* contain a function with signature

```
void Train(std::vector<Feature> features);
```

and therefore your compiler starts shouting.
You could technically fix your code just by declaring that virtual funciton, but it wouldn't really work, as there's a problem in your design, as mentioned in the previos response.